# Is there a better way to block raycast using transparent Image in UGUI(Unity new UI)?

Tags: android, iphone, user-interface, unity-game-engine, raycasting

Like when showing a popup dialog, I'm currently using Image that covers whole screen with alpha set to 0 so raycasting won't go beyond the dialog screen. And I use this tactic a lot, somtimes there're 3-5 of those transparent Images covering up my screen and makes me worried about performance.

So I'd like to know if there's better way to block raycasting in UGUI ( Except using Canvas Group's "Interactable" property since it's a big headache to turn on/off all the UI's under a dialog )

Comment: Are you using a transparent image or a blank -empty- image with alpha = 0?

Comment: The "source image" of Image is empty(or "none"). I've set alpha 0 in color property.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to block your personal "on game"/physics raycasting then you could try [UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject()](http://docs.unity3d.com/460/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem.html)

It will be true always when you are over a UI element so you can test before shot your raycast. I don't really know if it works properly with touch.

Comment: But thing is I still need to put something that covers whole screen for that method to work. I want to block UIs below the dialog but the dialog window itself doesn't cover the whole screen. If only there's some kind of "collider" that can block raycasting...

Comment: Understood, so why just doesn't create a global accessible manager to get a dialog "shown status" and use it before shot raycasts? When you open/show any dialog that you want to block raycasts set on this global manager, for example, UiManager.RayBlocker = true; If(!UiManager.RayBlocker){raycast}, remember to set false when this dialogs are closed/hidded =)

Comment: That would work and I will be likely using it. Though, it would be still nice if I can use some kind of collider to block raycast without performance loss as it will be code-less and simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Attach a CanvasGroup to the image object and check 'Block Raycasts' on it